# Android Error: Too many bind arguments. 1 arguments were provided but the statement needs 0 arguments

Tags: android, sqlite

I am deleting a database on Clicking a button and my delete method is as follows

```
 public int deleteDatabase(String tableName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

    String whereClause = null; // delete all rows
    String[] whereArgs = { null };
    int count = db.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
    db.close();
    return count;

}

 if (DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .isTableExists(MY_TABLE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Table exist, delete database");
            deleteDatabase(MY_LIST_TABLE);

        }
```

and the error is as follows: Too many bind arguments.  1 arguments were provided but the statement needs 0 arguments.

Comment: Post the StackTrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String whereClause = null; // delete all rows
String[] whereArgs = { null };
int count = db.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

if your provide a whereArgs, you have to provide also a valid where clause (with  the `?`placeholder). Change it like

```
int count = db.delete(tableName, null, null);
```